# Why is the 1st invocation of my C++ class method very expensive?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am learning C++ by coding some data structures and noticed that with my test code that the 1st invocation of Vector::add takes nearly 4x longer than the 2nd and 3rd invocation.

Please could someone explain why the 1st invocation is so expensive? I thought it was because of templates (so removed them), then because of not being inlined (so inlined it) and now I am trumped and just guessing it is because of the c++ runtime.

src/vector.h

```
//#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

class Vector {
public:
    explicit Vector(const int n);
    explicit Vector(const int n, const float val);
    float& operator[](const int i);
    inline int const length();
    inline void fill(const float val);
    inline void add(const float val)
    {
        chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = chrono::steady_clock::now();   
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            arr[i] += val;
        }
        chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        cout << "inside add took " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()
              << "us.\n";
    }
    inline float sum();
private:
    float* arr;
    int len;
};
```

vector_test.cpp

```
#include "vector.h"
#include "yepCore.h"
#include "yepLibrary.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    /* Initialize the Yeppp! library */
    yepLibrary_Init();
    const int n = 5000000;

    float *a = (float*) calloc(n, sizeof(float));
    yepCore_Add_V32fS32f_V32f(a, 1, a, n);

    float sum = 0;
    //cout << "starting tests" << '\n';
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = chrono::steady_clock::now();   
    Vector vec(n);
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << "vec constructor took " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()
              << "us.\n";

    start = chrono::steady_clock::now();    
    vec.add(1.0);
    end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << "1st vec add took " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()
              << "us.\n";   
    start = chrono::steady_clock::now();    
    vec.add(1.0);
    end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << "2nd vec add took " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()
              << "us.\n";
    start = chrono::steady_clock::now();    
    vec.add(1.0);
    end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << "3rd vec add took " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()
              << "us.\n";
    //std::cout << "a1 length = " << a1.length() << '\n';
    //std::cout << "a2[0] = " << a2[0] << '\n';
}
```

output:

```
vec constructor took 8us.
inside add took 11918us.
1st vec add took 11947us.
inside add took 2379us.
2nd vec add took 2405us.
inside add took 2374us.
3rd vec add took 2405us
```

Comment: Don't forget to also take a class that explains how demand-paged virtual memory operating systems work.  You are measuring page fault overhead.

Comment: Please show `Vector` constructors code and remove unrelated methods (basically, make the code you posted compilable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning on my telepathy skills, my guess is that in `Vector(const int n)` you allocate the memory for `arr` but don't initialize its contents (that's why vector creation is so fast). Therefore the actual allocation by operating system is happening when you first access the data, that is in the first `add()`.

Comment: Great telepathy skills... I tweaked my constructor and it's fine now :)